# Function reenters in interrupt

Tags: debugging, interrupt, reentrancy

I have function that prints debug output to UART. If interrupt occurs when this function works, then debug output from interrupt break previous debug text. So I have something like this:
"03:32:46 Loading data fr03:32:46 Button pressed".
I consider some solutions. I prefer not disable interrupts, instead of it disable debug output if it breaks other debug print function.
What is the good way for solving this problem?

Comment: You actually shouldn't things like print statements in the ISR, it's slow and might not be reeantrant.

Answer (score 0):

Basically don't do print statements in an ISR as this will have influences on the performance. If you want to know if an ISR was called (e.g. via a button press), try to this by setting output pins and toggling attached LEDs.

Use ISRs to set flags or perform short calculations.

Comment: It's good advice. But I have system with much work in ISR. It have to be redesigned. However now I do not actually know how to do it.